# Destroy and Create messages in UML

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

In UML we have two special messages, create and destroy. These two messages describe the creation and the destruction of objects, respectively. We must use the stereotypes << create >> and << destroy >> for them.  In the UML sequence diagram, I see that sometimes we create a message using a closed solid arrowhead and sometimes we create it using an open arrowhead. The same can be said for the destroy message. Here are examples :

[image]

[image]

Notice also that sometimes we draw the create message using a dotted arrow and another time using a solid arrow. This also confuses me!

So, What is the correct way to draw them? Or both ways are correct and can be used at any time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this is a frequent source of confusion.  But the notation for sequence diagram is clearly specified in the UML 2.5.1 specifications (p. 576-577) :

> - A reply Message (messageSort equals reply) has a dashed line with either an open or filled arrow head.
>   (...)
> - An object **creation** Message (messageSort equals createMessage) has a **dashed line with an open arrow head**.

All other kind of messages must have a plain line.  [Open and filled arrow heads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75849145/3723423), as well as other adornments all have specific meanings. The delete message must furthermore land on the destruction occurence specification (i.e. the X that crosses the lifeline).

Most people will understand the plain line with the `«Create»` stereotype (especially as this was the notation in UML 1.4, around 20 years ago).  But the specs make the difference, so that the dashed line  disambiguates the meaning, for example when the (optional) `«Create»` stereotype is not used and a combined fragment allows several alternative branches to create the same life line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I still can use a solid line but with a stereotype for both << create >> and << destroy >>, but what about the usage of the open arrow / closed arrow head  with a destroy message ?  Can I use any of them with the destroy message ?

Comment: @AAA you're welcome. I'd recommend to stick to the standard with a dashed line,  unless you work on a legacy project with old UML 1.4 notation. But ultimately, the most important thing is that readers understand your diagram. The arrow head is indeed not specified for the destroy message. Usually it is a plain arrow (because when landing on an X the open arrow head could overlap the X and be less visible.  But it would not be wrong to use an open head.  It's like the return arrow where both kind of arrow heads are explicitly accepted, but nobody really knows why, as there is no semantic diff.

Answer (score 2):

> Notice also that sometimes we draw the create message using a dotted arrow and another time using a solid arrow. This also confuses me!
>
> So, What is the correct way to draw them? Or both ways are correct and can be used at any time?

The correct way to draw a create message arrow is with a dashed line and open arrowhead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about the destroy message ?

Comment: @AAA, the line style of a destroy message is not specified, but it must end at a destruction occurrence (X through the lifeline), as already mentioned in the answer by Christophe.